# Error with sending sms in email with celery

Tags: python, django, celery

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter first_name'
}))
last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter last_name'
}))
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter username'
}))
email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter gmail'
}))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter password'
}))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control py-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter password again'
}))
captcha = CaptchaField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

# Email validation
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email is invalid')
    if len(email) >= 350:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Your email is too long')

    return email

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=True)
    # expiration = now() + timedelta(hours=48)
    # record = EmailVerification.objects.create(code=uuid.uuid4(), user=user, expiration=expiration)
    # record.send_verification_email()
    # return user
    send_email_verification.delay(user.id)
    return user 

 import uuid
 from datetime import timedelta

 from celery import shared_task
 from django.utils.timezone import now

 from user_account.models import EmailVerification, User


@shared_task
def send_email_verification(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    expiration = now() + timedelta(hours=48)
    record = EmailVerification.objects.create(code=uuid.uuid4(), user=user, expiration=expiration)

    try:
        record.send_verification_email()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send verification email: {e}")
```

I have a problem connecting celery to sending sms to mail in the console it says that I sent sms but the mail is empty when celery is off everything works how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example